# appendHtml() doesn't append the full HTML - Dart

Tags: javascript, html, dart

The following code works as expected in DartPad, demonstrated below:

```dart
void main() {
  Element e = querySelector('table');

  String someValue = 'hello, world';
  int anotherValue = 23958;

  Element row = new Element.tr()
    ..appendHtml('''
      <td>$someValue</td>
      <td>$anotherValue</td>
    ''');

  e.append(row);
}
```

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/7cc6b49fee17d47272ff)

However, when I compile the same code using dart2js (`dart2js -c -o app.js app.dart`) and run it on the same page, the created `<td>`'s are completely removed, and I end up with:

```
<table>
  <tr>hello, world 23958</tr>
</table>
```

The same issue occurs when the actual .dart file is used in `<script src="...">` with Dartium (v39.0.2171.0 x64). I'm on Dart v1.11.1.

---

**Some testing:**

```
..appendHtml('''
  <td></td>
  <td>hi</td>
''');
```

Yields:

```
<table>
  <tr>hi</tr>
</table>
```

This gives the same as above:

```
..appendHtml('<td>hi</td>');
```

The only way I could get it to give me what I want is:

```
..append(new Element.td()..text = someValue)
..append(new Element.td()..text = anotherValue.toString());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dart 1.11 made a change to appendHTML to sanitize the HTML input.

To avoid this, you can pass a sanitizer that does nothing.

```js
class MySanitizer implements NodeTreeSanitizer {
  void sanitizeTree(Node node) {}
}

document.body.appendHtml('<td>fish</td>', treeSanitizer: new MySanitizer());
```

Comment: Note: in v1.12.0, `NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted` can replace `new MySanitizer()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Should be fixed in bleeding edge very shortly, fix is in review. Basically, sanitization creates a document fragment to sanitize. It wasn't correctly using the context, so it tried to create it as it it was under body, and table elements don't work there.

Answer (score -2):

This is because JS does not support multiline strings, you would need to structure it like this:

```
'<td>TEXT</td>' +
'<td>TEXT2</td>'
```

OR:

```
'<td>TEXT</td><td>TEXT2</td>'
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript, it’s Dart – and Dart does support this syntax, see https://www.dartlang.org/articles/idiomatic-dart/#strings-and-interpolation

Comment: Javascript supports multiline strings..... its all one line until you break the line with a semi-colon (;)

Comment: @dane: ES6 supports it, not ES5. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m0rp30sc/ Can be hacked like this: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/11/09/javascript-es-5-hack-for-clean-multi-line-strings

Comment: @Slugge Unfortunately feeding either string into ..appendHtml() yields `<tr>TEXTTEXT2</tr>`. Plus, check my testing, I've tried that ;)